# How do I use HTMX with Django class based views?

Tags: django, htmx

I'm fairly new to htmx and django. I can implement htmx through function-based views OK, as I just call the function and return a `partial.html` file into the page.

However I don't understand how to make it work with class-based views I'm now using in Django.

I'd like to load comments on a blog post when a user clicks the **Load comments** button. My thought is that I'd need to use htmx to do a swap or insertion into a point on my page where I want the comments loaded.

Here is my `DetailView` where I load the detail of an individual post.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        print("method is being called")
        return render(request, "partial.html")
```

Here is my `partial.html` file that I'd like to be loaded into the page once the button on my `post_detail.html` page is clicked:

```
<h2 class="mt-2 mb-2">Comments:</h2>
{% if post.comments.all %}
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <div class="relative grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-4 mb-8 border rounded-lg bg-white shadow-lg">
            <div class="relative flex gap-4">
                <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                    <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
                        <p class="relative text-xl whitespace-nowrap truncate overflow-hidden">{{ comment.commenter }}</p>
                        <a class="text-gray-500 text-xl" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-gray-400 text-sm">{{ comment.date_added }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">{{ comment.body }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No comments</p>
{% endif %}
```

And here's the button in my `post_detail.html` page which I'm trying to use to send a `get` or `post` (I've tried both) request to my `post_detail` url/view.

```
                            <button hx-get="{% url 'posts:post_detail' %}" hx-target="#here">Press</button>
                    </div>
                <div id="here">Swap this text out</div>
```

Finally, here's my `urls.py` file:

```
app_name = "posts"
urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", CreatePostView.as_view(), name="create_post"),
    path("home/", HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("post/<int:pk>", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    path("edit/<int:pk>", EditPostView.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
]
```

My understanding was that I needed to use htmx to send a `get` or `post` request to my class based view `PostDetailView` which would call the `get()` or `post()`method and return my `partial.html` into the `hx-target` div with the `id` of "here".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What result are you getting? I think one issue is that the urlpattern for `post_detail` specifies a primary key parameter, so the button will need to pass it with something like this: `<button hx-get="{% url 'posts:post_detail' object.id %}" ...`

Comment: With the ```get``` request shown above my ```partial.html``` template is rendered on the entire page as soon as I go to the ```PostDetailView```. It's only meant to be rendered when I click a button in the on the Post Detail page itself, and obviously I just want the ```partial.html``` file to be loaded in to part of the Post Detail page, not all of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your View, you need to render the base template instead on first load i.e. normal get request.
But htmx get requests triggered from the button click should render the partial instead.

Requests triggered using htmx have a hx-request header appended to them, so it is possible to identify the source.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        print("method is being called")
        is_htmx = request.headers.get('HX-Request') == True
        if is_htmx:
            return render(request, "partial.html")

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```